# parsing the id's and classnames from a HTML file

Tags: php, html, cakephp, dom

I am able to parse tags from a html file using getElementByTagName. But i also want to parse the id's and classnames present in that html file...

This is what i have tried:-

```
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHTMLFile($url); //url is the url of the site
    $data = $html->getElementById($identifier); //identifier is the id
    $value = array();

    foreach($data as $element)
    {
        $value[] = $element->nodeValue."<br />";
    }
    print_r($value);
```

But when i use getElementById i just get output as array(). I am not able to parse the data.
And also can u please tell how to get the id and classname values ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to do a foreach loop as there can only be one element with a given ID:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154290/parsing-the-ids-and-classnames-from-a-html-file');

$element = $doc->getElementById('question');
if (!is_null($element)) {
    echo $element->getAttribute('class');
}
```

Comment: That's the attribute, so in the source of this page there is a div with the following:

`<div class="question" id="question">` so to get the class I would use `$element->getAttribute('class');`

Comment: look i hav ex:- <div id = "question" > but no class than what do i need to do ??

Comment: You can do the same for any attribute, so if you want to echo the ID just do `echo $element->getAttribute('id');`

Comment: Ok and one more doubt..getElementById('question'); this is to get id ??

Comment: look when i use echo $data->getAttribute('id'); i get the id name. I need to get the data present in that tag

Comment: Do `echo $element->nodeValue`

Comment: Thanks its working fine and even the procedure is same for classnames right ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25347/discussion-between-adam-and-pavan-k)

Comment: can we use getElementByClass ??

Answer (score 1):

I know an awesome tool php query  [phpquery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/).

```
phpQuery::newDocumentFileXHTML('my-xhtml.html')->find('#hello');
```

Here you can find  [examples](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Basics) .

Or you can use xpath it's nice too [xpath](http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Comment: what kind of result do you want ?